# How to create a similar image dataset of mnist with shape (12500, 50,50)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, mnist, numpy-ndarray

How to create a similar image dataset of mnist with shape (12500, 50,50)

I have a folder with 12500 images. I want to generate a datset with these images to work with sorting images in keras. I want to generate a dataset similar to mnist so that with shape (12500, 50,50). I'm wrapped up in creating the code to generate the dataset. I'm trying to create a numpy array but it's not getting the format I want. I believe I should use the opencv resize function to leave all images with height and width with 50x50 shape.
Grateful for the attention

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/Teste_datasets/PetImages/Cat/*.jpg")

for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    X_data.append (image)

X_data = np.array(X_data)

X_data = X_data.astype('float32') / 255

IMG_SIZE = 50

X_data = cv2.resize(X_data, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

X_data = X_data.reshape((X_data.shape[0], 50, 50,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should resize images, instead of the whole dataset:

```py
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/Teste_datasets/PetImages/Cat/*.jpg")
IMG_SIZE = 50

for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    X_data.append (image)

X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_data = X_data.astype('float32') / 255

print(X_data.shape)
```

```
[daniel@daniel-pc Keras]$ python3 testeKeras.py
<...>/2.png
<...>/1.png
(2, 50, 50)
```

Also, there's no reason to `reshape`, because since you load the image with  `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` you already have a single value representing the color.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now...I've got a question ... all of my 12,500 images have varying height and width sizes...greater than (50,50) ... for this code .. it's getting shaped like (143,50,50 ) instead of (12500,50,50) which is the total of images.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look, wait a minute. Meanwhile, could you check if `len(files)` is `12500`?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find what caused the error; it's working just fine in my machine. That's a very strange problem, because `X_data`should have the same length as `files` after the loop , even if the values of `image` were `None` or another invalid value.

Comment: I'll try again here. Thanks a lot for the help.